# Out of memory exception when using Geospatial queries in Spring Data ArangoDB

Tags: spring, gis, geospatial, arangodb

i'm using spring-boot 2.0.0 and arangodb-spring-data 2.0.3, i was following geospatial queries tutorial in [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Tutorial/Geospatial.html) with my own data structure.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(value = "hospital")
public class Hospital {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String address;
    @GeoIndexed
    private double[] location;

    public Hospital(String name, String phone, String address, double[] location) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.address = address;
        this.location = location;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface HospitalRepository extends ArangoRepository<Hospital> {
    GeoResults<Hospital> findByLocationWithin(Point location, Distance distance);
}

@Test
public void geoSpatialTest() throws IOException {
    populateDb();
    Point point = new Point(-7.2895286, 112.7731704);
    Distance distance = new Distance(2, Metrics.KILOMETERS);
    GeoResults<Hospital> results = repository.findByLocationWithin(point, distance);
    results.getContent().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

it'll throw out of memory exception **only** if i call findByLocationWithin() method.

```
com.arangodb.ArangoDBException: Response: 500, Error: 3 - AQL: out of memory (exception location: /var/lib/otherjenkins/workspace/RELEASE__BuildPackages/arangod/MMFiles/MMFilesGeoIndex.cpp:151) (while executing) (exception location: /var/lib/otherjenkins/workspace/RELEASE__BuildPackages/arangod/RestHandler/RestCursorHandler.cpp:135)
```

what i want to do is to get nearby hospital with distance less than X Km. I can achieve this by using this query in ArangoDB.

```
FOR hospital IN WITHIN(hospital, -7.2895286, 112.7731704, 2000)
RETURN hospital
```

Is arangodb-spring-data somehow broken? Do i need to make custom @Query for this?

Comment: Please provide the exact version of ArangoDB and storage engine in use.

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch the values for `Point` to do the same in your Java application as in your AQL query.

```
Point point = new Point(112.7731704, -7.2895286);
```

ArangoDB Spring data assumes that the first parameter of `Point` is longitude and the second latitude.

The Error `AQL: out of memory` occurs because of a check within the ArangoDB geo-index which checks that longitude is between -180 and 180 and latitude is between -90 and 90. The error message is very misleading but there is already a [PR on github](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/pull/5071) to fix this.

Comment: this solved my problem :D but it is a bit confusing since i need to use
`double[] location = {latitude, longitude}`
to store the data, and use
`new Point(longitude, latitude)`
for geospatial query.